# Migrate Json data with non-numeric unique identifier (from facebook...)

Tags: migrations, 9, social-network

I am trying to fetch posts form facebook, using **migrate**.

### My question is:

**in my migration conf.yml how should I set the source:ids key to handle non-numeric IDs, like the ones provided by facebook that look like that 1333842536759100_23306506123438**

---

**Some details:**

I fetch a json from FB that look like that:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "permalink_url": "URL",
         "created_time": "2021-11-06T16:59:16+0000",
         "is_popular": false,
         "message": "xxxxx",
         "id": "1333842536759100_23306506123438"
      }, {...}
   ]
}
```

In my source YML i've got:

```
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  track_changes: false
  urls:
    - 'XXX'
  item_selector: data
  fields:
    -
      name: id
      label: 'Unique post identifier'
      selector: id
   [...]
  ids:
    id:
      type: string
```

But when I try to import, I get:

```
Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out  
   of range value for column 'sourceid1' at row 1: INSE  
  RT INTO "migrate_map_facebook_posts" ("source_ids_has  
  h", "sourceid1", "source_row_status", "rollback_actio  
  n", "hash") VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_ins  
  ert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_inse  
  rt_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array     
  (                                                      
      [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => c21c5df349e2f4591c8  
  34b5342c35d69fca6f9aed586b75227057791d41b097b          
      [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1333842536759100_23306506123438                                         
      [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 3                    
      [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0                    
      [:db_insert_placeholder_4] =>                      
  )
```

Despite the ID type being set as "string", and I see in  my DB the column being int(13)...

How can I handle this non-numeric facebook ID ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was looking in the wrong place:
my yml was fine at this point, but before, I did import the migration conf with ids as integer.

The problem was that the database tables created by migrate (migrate_map_YOURMIGRATIONNAME and migrate_message_YOURMIGRATIONNAME ) won't get updated if you merely change and reimport your migration configuration.

In the end, I had to drop them manually for them to get recreated with the right structure.